# How to define many-many using fluent api with EF Core

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, domain-driven-design, ddd-repositories

I have one entity named `Team` and another entity `League`. Now let's say that i want to create a many-many relationship between them but with an additional column/property that i need to define from code (NOT generated by Db like a DateAdded column for instance). The extra property i'd like to have in place is the `Season`. That is what i've tried so far:

```
// Base entity contains the Id and a `DomainEvents` list accesible via `RegisterDomainEvent` method
public class Team : BaseEntity<Guid> 
{
    private Team() 
    {
        _teamLeagues = new(); 
    }

    public Team(Guid id, string name) : this()
    {
        Id = Guard.Against.Default(id);
        Name = Guard.Against.NullOrWhiteSpace(name);
        // other properties omitted for brevity
    }
    
    public string Name { get; } = default!;   

    private readonly List<TeamLeague> _teamLeagues;

    public IEnumerable<League> Leagues => _teamLeagues
        .Select(x => x.League)
        .ToList()
        .AsReadOnly();
    
    internal void AddLeague(TeamLeague league)
    {
        Guard.Against.Null(league);
        _teamLeagues.Add(league);
    }
}
```

```
public class League : BaseEntity<Guid>, IAggregateRoot
{
    // Required by EF 
    private League()
    {
        _teamLeagues = new();
    }

    public League(Guid id, string name) : this()
    {
        Id = Guard.Against.Default(id);
        Name = Guard.Against.NullOrWhiteSpace(name);
    }
    
    public string Name { get; } = default!;
    
    private readonly List<TeamLeague> _teamLeagues;
    public IEnumerable<Team> Teams => _teamLeagues
        .Select(x => x.Team)
        .ToList()
        .AsReadOnly();

    public void AddTeamForSeason(Team team, string season)
    {
        Guard.Against.Null(team);
        Guard.Against.NullOrEmpty(season);

        var teamLeague = new TeamLeague(Guid.NewGuid(), team, this, season);
        _teamLeagues.Add(teamLeague);
        team.AddLeague(teamLeague);

        TeamAddedToLeagueForSeasonEvent teamAdded = new(teamLeague);
        RegisterDomainEvent(teamAdded);
    }
}
```

```
public class TeamLeague : BaseEntity<Guid>
{
    private TeamLeague() { }
 
    public TeamLeague(Guid id, Team team, League league, string? season) : this()
    {
        Id = Guard.Against.Default(id);
        Team = Guard.Against.Null(team);
        League = Guard.Against.Null(league);
        Season = season;
    }
   
    public Team Team { get; }
   
    public League League { get; }

    public string? Season { get; } = default!;
}
```

Configuration:

```
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Team> builder)
{
     builder.ToTable("Teams").HasKey(x => x.Id);
     builder.Ignore(x => x.DomainEvents);
     builder.Property(p => p.Id).ValueGeneratedNever();
     builder.Property(p => p.Name).HasMaxLength(ColumnConstants.DEFAULT_NAME_LENGTH);
}
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<League> builder)
{
     builder.ToTable("Leagues").HasKey(x => x.Id);
     builder.Ignore(x => x.DomainEvents);
     builder.Property(p => p.Id).ValueGeneratedNever();
     builder.Property(p => p.Name).HasMaxLength(ColumnConstants.DEFAULT_NAME_LENGTH);

    builder
         .HasMany(x => x.Teams)
         .WithMany(x => x.Leagues)
         .UsingEntity<TeamLeague>(
            e => e.HasOne<Team>().WithMany(),
            e => e.HasOne<League>().WithMany())
         .Property(e => e.Season).HasColumnName("Season");
}
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<TeamLeague> builder)
{
    builder.ToTable("TeamLeagues").HasKey(x => x.Id);
    builder.Ignore(x => x.DomainEvents);
    builder.Property(p => p.Id).ValueGeneratedNever();
    builder.Property(p => p.Season).HasMaxLength(ColumnConstants.DEFAULT_YEAR_LENGTH);
}
```

Now from an api controller i want to create a new team and to assign it to the league also must be added to the intermediate table as well.

```
 // naive api controller, simple for demo reasons
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromRoute] Guid leagueId, Team team)
{
    var league = await _leagueRepository.GetByIdAsync(leagueId);
    league?.AddTeamForSeason(team, "2023");
    await _leagueRepository.UpdateAsync(league!);        
    return Ok(league);
}
```

```
// League Repository
public override async Task UpdateAsync(T entity, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    _dbContext.Set<T>().Update(entity);
    await SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
}
```

But by doing this i can't update neither the `Season` nor the (TeamLeague) Id.
How could i change the mapping (via fluent api again) in order to update that additional column on intermediate table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many hours of investigation i found the solution and i'd like to share it in any case someone else would like to use DDD with proper encapsulation.

So one way to solve this problem is to use this configuration for `League`

```
public class LeagueConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<League>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<League> builder)
    {
        builder
           .HasMany(x => x.Teams)
           .WithMany(x => x.Leagues)
           .UsingEntity<TeamLeague>(
               e => e.HasOne<Team>().WithMany("_teamLeagues"),
               e => e.HasOne<League>().WithMany("_teamLeagues"))
           .Property(e => e.Season).HasColumnName("Season");        
    }
}
```

So we keep "clean" our domain model having the `List<TeamLeague> _teamLeagues` still private but this time with this configuration we give access to EFCore to our private field in order to map it to the intermediate table.

Answer (score 0):

I found a similar solution but without the need to have an object that represents the intersect table (assuming its columns are TeamId and LeagueId):

```
public class LeagueConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<League>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<League> builder)
    {
        builder
            .HasMany(x => x.Teams)
            .WithMany(x => x.Leagues)
            .UsingEntity<Dictionary<string, object>>(
            "TeamLeague", // The name of the intersect table
            j => j
                .HasOne<Team>()
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey("TeamId")
                ,
            j => j
                .HasOne<League>()
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey("LeagueId")
        );
    }
}
```

This way you don't need to have additional classes in your project.

Comment: Straightforward solution thanks, but i intentionally keep the intersect table because of DDD concepts and the fact that there is "payload". But in another case where one doesn't need the complexity of DDD, then this is probably the best solution.

Comment: @ggeorge I'm curious - I'm also working on a DDD application and I need to save an object graph that is being updated in the UI, so it gets loaded by EF, transformed from a domain entity to a business entity, then ViewModel, gets update in the UI then transformed back to domain object to be persisted by EF. Do you know a way to make EF aware of the changes to the object graph so that EF's ChangeTracker knows what to update? I asked a question here, but haven't found a solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75607481/ef-core-fails-to-detect-changes-to-disconnected-object-graph

Comment: What about using domain events? That was the first idea that came to my mind when i read that the UI needs to notify somehow your BE. I think this way you will avoid to use separate contexts etc. Just an idea! :)